# Efficient SQl Query to get User favorite

Tags: java, postgresql

I am having three tables

```
USER
OFFER
USER_FAV_OFFER
```

User fav offer contains user id and offer id to join.
I can get users favorite offers with using join. 
but My problem is I need all offers and those offers also Detect it is already in favorite or not.

I can make two queries and using iteration between two loops, I can get the result but I think it is not an efficient way to do so. any good advice how to get all offers with favorite flag.

Edit:

```
select * from tbl_offer
left outer join tbl_user_book_marks on tbl_offer.id= tbl_user_book_marks.offer_id
```

Left outer join didn't work for me it gives me result with the redundunt result. I can not do group by as well coz I need bookmark flag from this query.

Comment: You will need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `OFFER` and `USER_FAV_OFFER`.

Comment: well, you missed the check for the `user_id`: `on .... and ...user_id=theCurrentUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query works for me

```
select is_bookmarked, tbl_offer.* from tbl_offer
    left outer join tbl_user_book_marks on tbl_offer.id= tbl_user_book_marks.offer_id
    and tbl_user_book_marks.user_info_id = USERID
```

USER ID will be pass from ui.